# Swift - Initialize enum from string in switch statement

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

Is it possible to test whether a specific enum type can be initialized by rawValue when switching on a string, instead of using if let?

```
static func getCurrency(from code: String) -> Currency? {
    if let fiatCurrency = Fiat(rawValue: code) {
        return fiatCurrency
    } else if let cryptoCurrency = Blockchain(rawValue: code) {
        return cryptoCurrency
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

This may be similar to type casting, where `currency` adheres to my Currency protocol:

```
switch currency {
case let fiatCurrency as Fiat:
    return getFiatFormatting(for: value, fiatCurrency: fiatCurrency)
case let blockchain as Blockchain:
    return getCryptoFormatting(for: value, blockchain: blockchain)
case let token as Token:
    return getTokenFormatting(for: value, token: token)
default:
    return nil
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can use the nil coalescing operator instead of `if let`.

`static func getCurrency(from code: String) -> Currency? {
    return Fiat(rawValue: code) ?? Blockchain(rawValue: code)
}`

You can add as many other possible enum initializations as you want. It'll evaluate in order and return the first that it's not `nil`. If all are `nil`, it returns `nil`. So, it has exactly the same behaviour as a series of `if-let-else`.

Comment: Definitely nicer, wasn't aware that it could be used consecutively.